# How to call the typealias in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, objective-c-blocks, type-alias

I've just started learning swift 3 and I'm converting this code in objective-c to swift 3 and I'm stuck at `typealias`. I've searched for it and there may be right help already available but it didn't solved my issue.

This is the line in objective-c:

```
typedef void (^TagBlock)(NSString *tagText, NSInteger idx);
```

And there is a property for it as `@property (nullable, copy) TagBlock tapBlock;` in objective-c.
Now I've converted the above line as:

```
typealias TagBlock = (_ tagText: NSString,_ idx: NSInteger) -> Void
```

Which is something I understand very well syntax wise and the property is `var tapBlock: TagBlock!` in case of swift.
Now as I try to call it in one of the `@IBAction` methods as:

```
if (tapBlock != nil) {
    self.setTapBlock(tapBlock: (tagButton.titleLabel?.text,tag) -> Void)
}
```

This gives an error as:

> Expected type before '->'

This line in objective is:

```
if (_tapBlock) {
    _tapBlock(sender.titleLabel.text, self.tag);
  }
```

**UPDATE** After `import UIKit` I've added `typealias TagBlock = ((String, Int) -> Void)?` and after that `var tapBlock: TagBlock!`
In `class TagView: UIView` I'm calling in in an `@IBAction` as

```
@IBAction func tagTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if (tapBlock != nil) {
            tapBlock?(sender.titleLabel.text, self.tag)
        }
    }
```

So at `tapBlock?(sender.titleLabel.text, self.tag)` it give me the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'TagBlock'`

Answer (score 3):

`nullable` is an optional in Swift, and in Swift 3 don't use underscores and parameter labels.

The equivalent is:

```
typealias TagBlock = ((String, Int) -> Void)?
```

and you can call it simply

```
tapBlock?(sender.titleLabel.text, self.tag)
```

Due to optional chaining the closure will not be called if `tapBlock` is `nil`.

Comment: it gives an error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'TagBlock'`

Comment: Another convention, I'm mentioning it for completion, is to use `Void` where the parameters are Void and `()` when the return type is void. so an alternative is `typealias TagBlock = ((String, Int) -> ())?`

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha Edit your question and add the code which causes the error.

Comment: Since the type alias is already an optional you have to declare `var tapBlock: TagBlock` (without exclamation mark). Anyway **never** declare optional completion blocks as implicit unwrapped (`!`), declare them always as standard optional (`?`). But the error seems to come from somewhere else.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having "cosmetic" argument labels by defining the typealias as `(_ tagText: String,_ index: Int) -> Void` – although they aren't used at the call site, they allow the author to be self-documenting.